# How do I transform a claim to a HMACSHA256 claim in an Azure B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am creating a custom policy to use Azure B2C as an IdP to integrate with a legacy auth service. The legacy service and the new IdP share a secret.

The legacy auth service has a custom authentication flow and requires that an HMACSHA256-based challenge token is sent to it as part of its Auth process using the shared secret as the key.

I am unable to find a way to create/transform a token to an HMACSHA256-based output claim. What are the recommended patterns to address a situation such as mine?

I tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/general-transformations#hash
but the computed hashes do not match.

Comment: you probably wanna create a  small (function) app that will do the trick for you and invoke it from your user journey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C doesn't create or transform HMACSHA254 token.

Also, it is not possible to do transformations on the resulting token. Claim transformation will only apply to claims in the claims bag.